# HTML5 video player with HTML-based playlist

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, playlist

How would I embed an HTML5 video player with an HTML-based playlist, using just unordered list & list item tags & anchor (link) tags? I don't want any of these fancy ones found across the web because they're too complicated to set up (& most of them aren't free). I just want to create a playlist that uses some basic JavaScript & that I can later style with CSS.

Thank you,

Jacob Saunders

Comment: A playlist like this would likely become as complicated as using an existing player that already has all the quirks worked out (and there are good ones like http://jplayer.org)

Answer (score 0):

Check out VideoJS https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.3.0/docs/guides/setup.md it is simple to setup and can be manipulated using JS.

Comment: Does it have playlist?

Answer (score 0):

**SuperSimple video player with playlist**

This is the simplest way i know. You can try to extend this function.with (li's and anchors,convert the array into an object....whatever)

```
function loadVids(vidsArray){
 for(var a=0,b,f=document.createDocumentFragment();b=vidsArray[a];++a){
  var c=document.createElement('div');
  c.textContent=b;
  f.appendChild(c);
 }
 d.appendChild(f);
}

var video=document.createElement('video'),
    vids=['video1.mp4','video2.mp4'],
    d=document.createElement('div');

d.onclick=function(e){if(e.target.parentNode==this){
 video.src=e.target.textContent;
 video.play();
}}

document.body.appendChild(video);
document.body.appendChild(d);
loadVids(vids);
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/e8CbF/